# java derby in Glassfish 3.1.2.2 shutsdown when i deploy my war file

Tags: web-services, amazon-ec2, glassfish, jax-rs

im running a glassfish 3.1.2.2 instance on my amazon ec2 , i have a web app "KowricService" web service in jax-rs ,i recently added some columns (Facebook_id,LinkedIn_id,Twitter_id,Gmail_id) to a table Users in the java derby backend, before this my application runs fine with no errors. i noticed now that when i deploy my war file,i get a ConnectionException error on my glassfish admin which occurs normally when the database is not running, meanwhile my database is running, i noticed each time i deploy it causes errors and shutsdown derby, occasionally it deploys fine, then it shutsdown after a while, what could be the causes?  could it be the extra columns i created? this is some part of my error stack.

```
[#|2013-11-   14T16:19:24.439+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/ubuntu/    glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/KowricService/WEB-INF/classes/$
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause:     Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to    server $
Error Code: 0                                                                                                                                                                          
Call: SELECT USER_ID, EMAIL, FACEBOOK_ID, FIRST_NAME, GOOGLE_ID, LAST_NAME, LINKEDIN_ID, PASSWORD, STATUS, TWITTER_ID, USER_TYPE FROM USERS                                            
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Users sql="SELECT USER_ID, EMAIL, FACEBOOK_ID, FIRST_NAME, GOOGLE_ID, LAST_NAME, LINKEDIN_ID, PASSWORD, STATUS, TWITTER_ID, USER_TYPE FROM     USERS").$
```

in the error stack trace it points to a rest resource method in a WebService class

```
   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:485)                                                                                   
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:742)                                                                                      
    at rest.UserResource.userList(UserResource.java:613)
```

and the method looks like this,

```
 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 @Path("/userslist")
 public List<Users> userList(){

  return em.createQuery("select u from Users u ").getResultList();
 }
```

im wondering if i added extra columns why this would cause an error, please help resolve.

EDIT:

```
i read further into the stack trace and noticed a ConnectionPool Exception,i actually     have 2 copies of a JNDI resource pointing to the same pool,could this be the reason; 

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection     could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server     54.200.6.$
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:120)                                                                                                          
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:123)                                                                                              
    ... 122 more  

at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:123)                                                                                              
    ... 122 more                                                                                                                                                                   
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a  connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException :   Error conne$
    at   com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManager Impl.java:307)                                                                   
    at  com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImp l.java:190)                                                                      
    at   com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImp   l.java:165)                                                                      
    at   com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImp l.java:160)                                                                      
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:113)                                                                                                          
    ... 123 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally sorted it out,i read down the stack trace,it kept pointing to a jndi conflict, so i deleted one from the jdbc resources and i noticed the jndi name on the persistence.xml file had been altered so i re-configured it.